# How to split a sentence in two halves in R

Tags: r, string

I have a vector of string, and I want each string to be cut roughly in half, at the nearest space.

For exemple, with the following data :

```
test <- data.frame(init = c("qsdf mqsldkfop mqsdfmlk lksdfp pqpdfm mqsdfmj mlk",
      "qsdf",
      "mp mlksdfm mkmlklkjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjklmmjlkjll",
      "qsddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd",
      "qsdfmlk mlk mkljlmkjlmkjml lmj mjjmjmjm lkj"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I want to get something like this :

```
                              first                                       sec
1          qsdf mqsldkfop mqsdfmlk                lksdfp pqpdfm mqsdfmj mlk
2                              qsdf                                    
3                        mp mlksdfm mkmlklkjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjklmmjlkjll
4 qsddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd                                        
5                  lmj mjjmjmjm lkj                        lmj mjjmjmjm lkj
```

Any solution that does not cut in halves but "so that the first part isn't longer than X character" would be also great.

Comment: you are right I corrected the exemple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, we split the strings by spaces.

```
a <- strsplit(test$init, " ")
```

Then we find the last element of each vector for which the cumulative sum of characters is lower than half the sum of all characters in the vector:

```
b <- lapply(a, function(x) which.max(cumsum(cumsum(nchar(x)) <= sum(nchar(x))/2)))
```

Afterwards we combine the two halfs, substituting `NA` if the vector was of length 1 (only one word).

```
combined <- Map(function(x, y){
  if(y == 1){
    return(c(x, NA))
  }else{
   return(c(paste(x[1:y], collapse = " "), paste(x[(y+1):length(x)], collapse = " ")))
  }
}, a, b)
```

Finally, we `rbind` the combined strings and change the column names.

```
newdf <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, combined)
names(newdf) <- c("first", "second")
```

Result:

```
> newdf
                              first                                  second
1           qsdf mqsldkfop mqsdfmlk               lksdfp pqpdfm mqsdfmj mlk
2                              qsdf                                    <NA>
3                        mp mlksdfm mkmlklkjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjklmmjlkjll
4 qsddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd                                    <NA>
5                       qsdfmlk mlk         mkljlmkjlmkjml lmj mjjmjmjm lkj
```

Comment: The `y == 1` here should be `length(x) == 1`. Otherwise, this doesn't work when the line break should happen after the first word.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the function `nbreak` from the package that I wrote:

```
devtools::install_github("igorkf/breaker")
library(tidyverse)

test <- data.frame(init = c("Phrase with four words", "That phrase has five words"), stringsAsFactors = F)

#This counts the numbers of words of each row:
nwords = str_count(test$init, " ") + 1

#This is the position where break the line for each row:
break_here = ifelse(nwords %% 2 == 0, nwords/2, round(nwords/2) + 1)

test
#                        init
# 1     Phrase with four words
# 2 That phrase has five words

#the map2_chr is applying a function with two arguments,
#the string is "init" and the n is "break_here":
test %>%
  mutate(init = map2_chr(init, break_here, ~breaker::nbreak(string = .x, n = .y, loop = F))) %>%
  separate(init, c("first", "second"), sep = "\n")
#             first     second
# 1     Phrase with four words
# 2 That phrase has five words
```